# How do I convert the x, y, and zoom coordinates of a map tile to the corresponding coordinates in a quadtree map system?

Tags: python, google-maps, dictionary, pseudocode, quadtree

I am trying to access map tiles from a web service.

The tiles are organized in a [quad-tree like this](http://docs.overviewer.org/en/latest/design/designdoc/#quadtrees). In the filesystem, they are organized so that `3/0/0/1/1/2.png`, for example, refers to the tile starting at the base, under the third quadrant, then the 0th quadrant, then the 0th, and so fourth.

In my application, I am asked for the x, y, and zoom values of a map tile, and I have to return a URL. How do I convert these values to the file path format described above?

I [found](http://www.dzone.com/snippets/converting-between-2-google) this python script, which claims to turn x, y, and zoom values into google maps tile identifier that can be used somehow to access a given tile, but I cannot figure out how I would modify it to output in the format I want:

```
def quadtree(x,y, zoom):
    out = []
    m = {(0,0):'q', (0,1):'t', (1,0):'r', (1,1):'s'}
    for i in range(17-zoom):
        x, rx = divmod(x, 2)
        y, ry = divmod(y, 2)
        out.insert(0, m[(rx,ry)])
    return 't' + ''.join(out)
```

Heres an example execution of that:

```
>>> quadtree(20,49,10)
'tqtsqrqt'
```

What I would like to happen:

```
>>> quadtree(5,3,3)
    '2/1/3'
```

This is obviously not near the output that I would like, but it seems to be a starting point (I guess).

I will take a solution or suggestion in any coding language (or pseudocode).

Comment: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames Does that help?

Comment: @JohnBarça Doesn't look like those are in a quadtree arrangment.

Comment: XYZ to quadtree with C# code from Bing of all places: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx

Comment: have you tried replacing qtrs with 0123?

Comment: Can you give example input and output?

Comment: @Nicolas78 That works! Go ahead and put it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace 'q','t','r' and 's' with 0,1,2 and 3, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

There is a small PyPi packages which helps with the conversion.
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyGeoTile

It's from the pyGeoTile repository on Github.
https://github.com/geometalab/pyGeoTile

And here a usage example:

```
from pygeotile.tile import Tile

tms_x, tms_y, zoom = 134494, 329369, 19
tile = Tile.from_tms(tms_x=tms_x, tms_y=tms_y, zoom=19)  # Tile Map Service (TMS) X Y and zoom

print('QuadTree: ', tile.quad_tree)  # QuadTree:  0302222310303211330
print('Google: ', tile.google)  # Google:  (134494, 194918)
```